# JQ command not working in python

Tags: python, json, subprocess, jq

So I have a jq command that converts my json array into a json object. The command works normally in the windows terminal, but when I try to implement it into my python program i get this: jq: error:

```
Could not open file >newfile.json: Invalid argument.
```

Here is my jq command which works and puts the transformed json into newfile.json:

```
jq ".[]" data.txt >newfile.json
```

Here is my subprocess call in my python program:

```
 subprocess.call('jq ".[]" data.txt >newfile.json', cwd=r'C:/Users/john/Desktop/swag', shell=True)
```

Comment: To get the subprocess module to handle shell features such as redirection, you need to add ``shell=True`` to the call.

Comment: I've already done this sorry I forgot to add that to my question, but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Clearly a Windows-specific problem. Not having a Windows system available to test with, the easy answer is to give a solution that bypasses relying on the shell to do things for you altogether.

Comment: Why are you using `jq` for this when Python has a `json` library built right in?

Comment: I don't really know how to manipulate json with the python built in library, and know more jq. Do you have any documentation that I should read? I can't really find exactly what I need

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the output file yourself, and you won't need to rely on shell behavior (which is, obviously, not working in the present case) to do it for you.

```
subprocess.call(['jq', '.[]', 'data.txt'],
  cwd=r'C:/Users/john/Desktop/swag',
  stdout=open('C:/Users/john/Desktop/swag/newfile.json', 'w'))
```